# Converting (symmetrical) line to neutral to line to line components

Tags: circuit-analysis, three-phase

I have given the unbalanced line to neutral three phase voltages, and I have to find the unbalanced line to line voltages. Therefore I have calculated the line to neutral (symmetrical) components using decomposition, but I am not sure how to convert the line to neutral components into line to line components. 
Once I can get the line to line components, I can apply synthesis to obtain the unbalanced line to line voltages(three phase).
Can anyone explain a little bit theory on this topic, please 
It would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since you know the line to neutral Voltages in the symetrical system ( 3 times 120 deg) you can use the law of cosines to calculate the line - line voltages.